# Properties of characteristic functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory

X is a exponential random variable with parameter a.

The characteristic function of X is:

$\varphi_X(t)=\dfrac {a}{a-it}$

I want to calculate the characteristic function of 3X.

I know the property:

If Y = bX, then $\varphi_Y(t)=\varphi_X(bt)$

Using the property

$\varphi_{3X}(t)=\varphi_X(3t)=\dfrac {a}{a-i3t} $

It is correct?

Comment: Yes, what doubts do you have?

Comment: I was reviewing the forum before asking the question and I found this link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3172186/let-x-and-y-two-independent-random-variables-with-exponential-distribution -of-pa. There is something similar to my question (in the solution) and the characteristic function for 2X would not match what the property establishes. That made me doubt. Thanks

Comment: Indeed the linked post is confusing and, after checking the mathematics myself, I think, is a little sloppy. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\phi_X(t)=\frac{a}{a-it}$ we have that
$$\phi_Y(t)=\mathbb{E}(e^{itcX})=\phi_X(ct)=\frac{a}{a-ict}=\frac{a/c}{a/c-it}.$$

Now, let us  verify this in another way. If $X$ is exponentially distributed with parameters $a$, so that the mean is $\mathbb{E}(X)=1/a$ then if $Y=cX$ where $c>0$ we have that the CDF of $Y$ is
$$\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq y/c)=1-e^{-ay/c},$$
hence $Y$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $a/c$. Thus, it must have CF as
$$\phi_Y(t)=\frac{a/c}{a/c-it}=\frac{a}{a-ict}.$$

With this in mind, the linked post in your comment on the main thread appears to be a little sloppy with regard of keeping track of the parameter and mean and the effect of scaling them.